# bottom navigation selected item highlight

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a problem with bottom navigation menu in android with kotlin
I can't disable icon highlight for selected item , any body can help me ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGXd4.jpg)

I searched web but I can't find any solution for hide highlight around icon in bottom navigation menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using xml:

```
val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
bottomNavigationView.itemActiveIndicatorColor = getColorStateList(R.color.black)
```

for compose set color of `NavigationBarItem`:

```
colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(indicatorColor = Color.Black)
```

Answer (score 0):

its work for me , thank you.

i define an transparent hex color in color.xml :

```
<color name="transparent">#00FFFFFF</color>
```

and use below code for set this transparent hex color code for bottmnavigation to hide icon highlight :

```
binding.bottomNav.itemActiveIndicatorColor = getColorStateList(R.color.transparent)
```

ijust change it to viewBinding